# How can I add Shift+Right-Click SendTo items in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, context-menu, right-click, shift

Unlike Windows XP, in Windows 7 appear more items in **Send to** menu when you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> before right click. You can easily add shortcuts to simple right click copying them to `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` (`shell:SendTo`).

How can you add items to appear only when you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Extended Send To" menu is found in the folder `%userprofile%`.

Add or delete shortcuts to it the same as you do with `shell:SendTo`.

For more information see [this article](https://www.askvg.com/tip-customize-hidden-extended-send-to-menu-in-windows-add-or-remove-shortcuts/).